# Sum two columns and display on third column

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I want to sum two columns that have numerical values and display the results on the third column. I have the script below but that deletes the two columns and display the results on the first column.

Any suggestions?

```
function test2() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var rng = ss.getRange('E2:F6');
  var val = rng.getValues();

  for(row=0;row<val.length;row++) {
    val[row][0] =val[row][0]+val[row][1];;
    val[row][1] = '';
  }
  rng.setValues(val)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Using map:

```
function one() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getActiveSheet();
  const vs = sh.getRange('E2:F6').getValues().map(r => [r[0],r[1],r[0]+r[1]]);
  sh.getRange(2,5,vs.length,vs[0].length).setValues(vs);
}
```

|  | E | F | G |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | COL5 | COL6 |  |
| 2 | 5 | 6 | 11 |
| 3 | 6 | 7 | 13 |
| 4 | 7 | 8 | 15 |
| 5 | 8 | 9 | 17 |
| 6 | 9 | 10 | 19 |

- [Array.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead.  Just get the colum G and overwrite anything in it with the sum.

```
function test() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var rng = ss.getRange('E2:G6');  // just get the extra column
  var val = rng.getValues();

  for(row=0;row<val.length;row++) {
    val[row][2] = val[row][0]+val[row][1];
    val[row][1] = '';
  }
  rng.setValues(val)
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this. It works by displaying the results on the third column. However, it still deletes the two first columns with the initial values.

If I take this line from the script `val[row][1] = '';`, then it works. Thanks!

Comment: It should not delete the first but you showed it deleting the second with `val[row][1] = '';`.